# Como fazer um hover box

Tags: html5, css3

Boa noite, eu vi no seguinte site https://cheftech.com.br/funcionalidades/ um hover box interessante, ele tem um formato de card e vira quando o mouse passa por cima, eu pesquisei sobre o componente mas não achei um exemplo igual ao do site acima, somente variações. Alguém teria esse exemplo ou sabe o nome exato desse efeito ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O nome desse tipo de "componente" é *flipcard*, ele é amplamente usado por ai e não é difícil de trabalhar com ele depois que se entende a forma como funciona.

Mas vc pode pesquisar tutoriais por ai que vc encontra aos montes, aqui mesmo tem um do nosso querido Maujor https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/criando-animacao-flipping-com-css.php

As dicas básicas que vou te dar são as seguintes. O elemento do `:hover` dever ser o *container* mais externo, do contrário quando o cartão virar a sua "área ativa" vai sumir da tela por um instante e vai *buggar* o efeito. Inclusive coloque o `perspective` no `container` externo também, para dar a profundidade correta do efeito.
 **Ex** de código com esse bug no `:hover`: https://codepen.io/wandersonsilva/pen/rVpPOW

```
.container { perspective: 800; } /* brinque com esse valor para entender melhor */
```

Outro ponto importante é a propriedade `backface-visibility: hidden` ela faz com que a parte de traz do seu `card` só apareça quando ela for girada para frente e também esconde a frente do `card` quando ela estiver rotacionada para traz caso o `card` não tenha um background.

O `transform-style: preserve-3d` é o que vai dar o efeito de 3D quando o `card` girar no próprio eixo, junto como o `perspective` vai dar a impressão do cartão "saltar" a tela em direção ao usuário que olha a tela.
 **Ex** de código sem o efeito `perspective` https://codepen.io/provob/pen/ogLEww

Mais uma vez, para entender melhor não deixe de ler, aqui tem outro artigo https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Aqui segue um  exemplo prático. ***(Deixei os comentários no código)***

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-size: 2.2em;
  margin: 0;
}

.card-container {
  /* é a "distancia relativa" entre o movimento do cartão e o quento ele se "aproxima" na tela do usuário - Brinque com esse valor pra testar */
  perspective: 800px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  /* faz o efeito do flip no proprio eixo parecer em 3D */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


.front, .back {
  background: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* esconde o lado que estiver na parte de traz do card caso não tenha um background no card */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* quando fizer o hover o carde dentro do containr flipa */
.card-container:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <h2>Goodbye</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Fonte:* https://codepen.io/jeffaustin81/pen/qERoqR

Comment: Vou estudar esse conteúdo, muito obrigado!

Comment: @slyfer isso ai, leia, refaça o código do seu jeito, veja exemplos, e principalmente, pega o código e brinque com os valores, tira uma propriedade ou outra para ver o que acontece etc, isso vai te ajudar muito a entender a dinâmica da coisa. Boa sorte ai []´s